# Google Sheets: Whats the formula to count all Sundays from a list of dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I count a specific date from a list of dates?

So I want to count all dates in the format of mm/dd/yyyy for Sundays.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/La0Ru.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WEEKDAY()` function.

Specifically, your function would look a little like this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(1 = WEEKDAY("CellRange",1),1,0)))`

The `1` in the `1 = Weekday` refers to the day of the week in the weekday notation can be changed. You would change this number based on what day you would want (Monday would be a 2, Saturday would be a 7).

For some reason there seems to an issue with the Saturday value. I am not sure what is going on with it, but here is a workaround:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF( IF(ISBLANK(CellRange),1 = 2,7 = WEEKDAY(CellRange,1)),1,0)))`

This just adds in an `IF()` statement that returns false if the cell is empty

Comment: Hello VPK,
Every day seems to work except Saturday. For Saturday's Results, it seems to double the results. Any idea how this is happening?

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the change. There might be some root problem I am missing here, but the addidtional IF() statement can be used for all days (naturally subbing out for day index and cell range)

Comment: Thank you! This finally did it. I appreciate your response! +1